# Bootstrap collapse is delayed on show

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made Java Web application based on this web template https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/

(Using Bootstrap v3.3.6 and jQuery v2.2.3)

I didn't change any bootstrap js and css, but collapse is working without transition and show phase is delayed.

I could simulate it with changing css like this: http://codeply.com/view/mLlDDWAF1G

I need it to work instantly on click. Can you help somehow, please?

Thanks, Filip

Answer (score 0):

Custom transition property overriding the bootstrap's default collapse. When you will remove it transition will be smooth and instant.Remove the transition defined in the following css:

```
.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.collapse.show {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If you still want to reduce the collapse delay than in bootstrap.js file you can reduce the value of `Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION` and you will be done.

Comment: Did not the OP did the same thing in his code link! Problem is not transitioning any more, its `timeout()`. "I need it to work instantly". You just copy/paste OP code as an answer!

Comment: @ColinCline I suggested to remove this css instead of adding this css because this css overriding bootstrap's default transition and you can see it's not smooth. Also, I have updated my answer and added the way to reduce the transition duration.

Comment: Problem is not transition duration anymore. Some how you most modifie `setTimeOut()` if there is exists in bootsrtap js or `transition-delay`, thats need hard core override.

Comment: @ColinCline I am agree with your point it will override bootstrap's default behavior. But it's not possible to change the transition duration as here Flip is using bootstrap's collapse class. The only way to achieve that without overriding bootstrap's CSS is to avoid the use of collapse class of bootstrap and write the custom one.

Comment: Agree, making a custom one is a better solution but I think it could be hard for OP.

Comment: I have gone through the bootstrap documentation as well and they do not provide this to be done dynamically and value of Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION is hardcoded there in bootstrap.js file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184891/discussion-between-aditi-and-colin-cline).

Comment: Thanks for tips. None of it has solved my problem. Only solution that I see is to write own class, but this is not so big bug for me, so I will let it as it is. Again thanks a lot.